# L'argot ne s'accorde pas ?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, accord, argot, langage-des-jeunes

J'ai constaté, peut-être à tort, que quelques mots d'argot, par exemple super, top, etc., ne s'accordent pas quand ils sont employés en tant qu'adjectifs.

> Ils sont top ! Elles sont super !

Alors que je ne vois jamais :

> Ils sont tops ! Elles sont superes !

Bien que les adjectifs en général doivent être accordés, bien sûr:

> Ils sont incroyable**s**, elles sont divin**es**

Je me demande donc :

1. Est-ce que ce constat est vrai, et si c'est le cas :
2. Qu'est ce qui explique la manque d'accord, et
3. Est-ce qu'il pourrait être généralisé ?

Comment: effectivement super est invariable. Pour ce qui est de "devines", s'agit-il plutôt de l'adjectif "divines" ?

Comment: Tout à fait, c'était un typo, merci.

Comment: Les mots tels que « super » et « top » ne sont pas de l'argot, ce sont du [franglais](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franglais).

Comment: @LPH Je me demande si *ce sont du franglais* est du français.

Comment: @jlliagre Ce n'est pas une construction qui me semble habituelle, et on ne la trouve pas ; on peut l'appeler non-idiomatique ;  « ce sont des mots de franglais » est correct.

Comment: @LPH Tu te compliques la vie, il suffit de dire *c'est du franglais*. D'ailleurs, c'est surtout du latin, aussi loin que *super* est concerné... ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'usage n'est pas figé, il évolue lentement de l'invariabilité (encore la plus courante aujourd'hui) vers une normalisation de l'accord au pluriel.

D'après le TLFi, *[**super**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/super/1)* en tant qu'adjectif est invariable.

C'est aussi l'avis d'[Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/super_1) et du [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/super/75410) mais le [Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/super) accepte l'accord comme l'absence d'accord au pluriel:

> *Des soirées supers ou super (invariable).*

On retrouve le même cas avec ***extra*** :

> [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/extra)  :
> Les dictionnaires modernes et les ouvrages traitant d'orthographe qui relèvent que *extra* est invariable en nombre notent l'usage du XIX<sup>e</sup>s. Depuis le début du XX<sup>e</sup>s., l's du pluriel tend à se généraliser (*supra* ex. 2 et Mirbeau, *loc. cit.*), sans que l'invariabilité soit totalement exclue : *nous mettions en panne pour échanger ces extra de boustifailles contre du café, du tabac* (Cendrars, Bourlinguer, 1948, p. 178).

> [Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/extra)
> *Des chocolats extras.*

> [Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/extra)
> *Des produits extra ou extras.*

Les deux derniers dictionnaires de l'Académie (1932 et 2005) indiquent l'invariabilité même en tant que substantif:

> 8e édition: ***EXTRA**, pris comme nom, se dit dans le langage familier pour désigner un Supplément ajouté aux choses habituelles, au train ordinaire, surtout du repas, un Serviteur ou un employé supplémentaire. On fit un petit extra. Il commanda deux plats d'extra. Il ne prend pas la marque du pluriel. On adjoignit deux extra aux domestiques de la maison.*

> 9e édition: ***EXTRA**, adjectif invariable
>
> III.
>
> XIXe siècle. Abréviation d'extraordinaire. Pop. Pour désigner un produit de qualité supérieure.*

Top est indiqué comme invariable par [Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/extra) et [le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/top) :

> ***TOP** adjectif invariable Supérieur, excellent. Elles sont top.*

D'autre part, on ne rencontre pas l'accord au féminin:

> *Elles sont topes !* ﹖﹖﹖
> *Elles sont supères !* ﹖﹖﹖

Une explication de la nature initialement invariable de ces mots pourrait être leur caractère adverbial (*Ils sont super bons tes gâteaux.*) ou préfixal (*supermamie*).

Tout ceci n'a pas de rapport avec l'argot, d'ailleurs ces adjectifs ne sont pas de l'argot mais simplement familiers. Les mots et adjectifs argotiques n'ont pas de spécificité dans ce domaine et suivent donc normalement les règles d'accord habituelles.

Comment: Bien développé, merci.